# Access theme variables outside withStyles function (react-native-ui-kitten)

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

I want to use theme variables to style my Icon accordingly. However i cant use style property to fill the Icon element of react-native-ui-kitten but instead have to use the fill property. How can I access theme variables outside of the withStyles function of react-native-ui-kitten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xk2tm5ah5c
You can use `theme` property if you wrap your component into `withStyles`.

Here is an example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Icon, withStyles } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

const ScreenComponent = (props) => {

  const iconColor = props.theme['color-primary-default'];

  const FacebookIcon = (style) => (
    <Icon {...style} fill={iconColor} name='facebook' />
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Button icon={FacebookIcon}>LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK</Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export const Screen = withStyles(ScreenComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what i was looking for. Gonna try it out later, but marking your answer as correct now in case i forget

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question completely. Usually when you have a question, you should post some of your code for context.

Here is my answer assuming 'Theme variable' is a hash... Try string interpolation:

```
fill={`${theme.HEX_COLOR}`}
```

Comment: I didnt have a theme variable that was the problem :) i wanted to have access to the theme dicitionary that react-native-ui-kitten provides. The answer of artyorsh is what i was looking for. But thanks for your suggestion anyway.